# Make web laravel application with microservices

Tags: laravel, microservices

This is my web structure actually :

```
App
-> src
    -> Http
        -> Auth/
        -> Activity/
        -> GeoCoding/
```

And I would like transform my monolithique application to scalable application with microservices :

```
App <- AuthModule
App <- ActivityModule
App <- GeoCodingModule
```

With `*Module` as NodeJs Module.

But I have different problems :

- how to use modules as Laravel middleware per example
- should modules return json format ? Or url/ view ?

So, I don't know if my microservices have to be Node package, or Composer package (maybe with Lumen ?) ?

I'm lost with microservice concept.

Source :
http://wiki.c2.com/?MonolithicDesign
https://martinfowler.com/articles/microservices.html